# vector<A> vs vector<A*> vs vector<shared_ptr<A> > in C++

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a `class A` which is neither copy-constructable nor assignable. Now I want another `class B` to hold a vector of `A` objects. It is also clear that `B` holds the ownership of these objects.

As I see it, there are (at least) three options:

1. use `vector<A>`
2. use `vector<A*>`
3. use `vector<shared_ptr<A> >`

Is it right that 1. does not work because `A` is not copy constructable / assignable?

I don't like 2. because I have to make sure that I delete the pointers again.

If I use 3. I feel like this does not clearly represent that `B` is the owner of the `A` objects. Also I run into the issue that if I want users of `B` to delete pointers from this vector they need to pass the element they want to delete by `shared_ptr<A>`, right?

What would be a clean design decision in this case? Are there any good references on this?

Comment: Is A movable ? 4. `std::unique_ptr` as you don't share owner ship.

Comment: [std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: What do you want to do with your vector of `A`? This is the main question  you should ask yourself before chosing which one is the right to use.

Comment: I want users of `B` to request elements of the vector and them also being able to delete these elements e.g. by a call to `B::delete(some_type_of_A)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct; `A` needs to be [copy-assignable and copy-constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to be used with `std::vector`, but from C++11 on, this depends very much on the operations you need to use on the vector.
2. I agree, I would not use raw pointers anymore unless I had a very compelling reason (and this isn't one in my opinion).
3. Have you considered `unique_ptr`? There's a nice [blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/20/c11-using-unique_ptr-with-standard-library-containers) on that option.

Comment: Nice reference. Does this mean that I would usually pass around `const unique_ptr(A)&` instead of `A*` or `const A&` ?

Comment: Hmm, depends on your use case I guess, but if you really need to pass around pointers (even outside of your `B`), maybe you _should_ use `smart_ptr` instead. I would either do that, or just pass `const A&` around. Holt's comment to your question has the right idea – maybe you need to clarify your use cases some more.